# always lift up states of react child components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

My react-materialUI app has multiple dialogs, and some of these dialogs are containing the same mui data grid (a list of projects).

Example: a save project dialog. This dialog contains this mui data grid and a mui text field, both as child components.

By clicking on a row in the data grid, I want to set the content of the text field to the value of the selected row.
To accomplish this, I could lift up the value state of the text field and the selectedRow state of the data grid to the save dialog.

somehow I find it hard to understand that a supposedly reusable component isn’t handling their state by itself.

Is lifting states up really the best practice or is there something basic I overlooked?

Comment: You can use `useContext`

Comment: This is what [useContext and reducers](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/scaling-up-with-reducer-and-context) ([and/or redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)) are for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some behavior in the data grid should affect the value of the text field, you probably need to lift the state for that text value.

But you might not need to lift the state for the data grid. Instead, you could pass an `onSelect` prop which you use to set the text value, something like:

```js
<DataGrid onSelect={(project) => setText(project.name)} />
```

*Further reading*

The beta React docs have great content on such topics, e.g. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/thinking-in-react#step-4-identify-where-your-state-should-live